# Visual Studio incremental link auto recovery after invalid library

Tags: visual-studio, linker, build-process

I am using 3rd party build system (boost jam) that controls the build and link process. If I cancel the build process it force stops the linking (if any is active) that very often leaves libraries (and executables) in unreliable state.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio incremental link option to use the full link in case of incremental error.